# How to merge join two matrixes?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, manipulate, data

First, I have a 3x3x2 matrix A, which looks like:

[image]

then i have a 3x3x1 matrix B, which is:

[image]

How to merge the B into A and make a 3x3x3 matrix by appending each of the element of B into corresponding position in A matrix?

the result should be look like:

[image]

Comment: could you post the Mathematica code for the input? i.e. A and B?

Comment: @Nasser yes its Table[{x,y},{y,3},{x,3}] and Table[{x},{y,3},{x,3}]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
ma = Array[Subscript[a, #1, #2] &, {3, 3, 2}];
MatrixForm[ma]
```

[image]

```
mb = Array[Subscript[b, #1, #2] &, {3, 3, 1}];
MatrixForm[mb]
```

[image]

```
mc=Join[ma, mb, 3];
MatrixForm[mb]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
alist = {{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}, {{1, 
     3}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}}};
blist = {{{1}, {2}, {3}}, {{1}, {2}, {3}}, {{1}, {2}, {3}}};

Dimensions /@ {alist, blist}

(dlist = Table[
    alist[[i, j]] ~Join~blist[[i, j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 
     3}]) // MatrixForm
```

Or

```
(elist = MapThread[Join, {alist, blist}, 2]) // MatrixForm

Dimensions /@ {dlist, elist}
```

---

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html):

```
{ma, mb} = {Array[Subscript[a, Row[{##}]] &, {3, 3, 2}], 
  Array[Subscript[b, Row[{##}]] &, {3, 3, 1}]};

Flatten[{ma, mb}, {{2}, {3}, {1, 4}}]

MatrixForm @ %
```

[image: ![enter image description here]